# Makefile executes only first part of command

Tags: makefile, g++

I would appreciate if anyone could explain the following behavior to me

(Please do keep in mind I am COMPLETELY new in Makefile creation and I'm probably totally overlooking something. I'm only trying to use it to automate a compilation process)

```
client2:
    g++ client.cpp -o client.app --std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -lTgBot -lboost_system -lboost_iostreams -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread
```

(tab is inserted before "g++")

I am using the line above to execute a g++ command. However only this part of the command is executed when I use "make client2":

```
:~/**some-location-anything-anywhere**$ make client2
g++     client2.cpp   -o client2
```

I'm confused as to why the rest of the g++ command is ignored and thus my compilation process completely fails (the command does work when I manually enter it into a shell). Am I missing out on something?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like it uses implicit rule to build executable from `.cpp` file. Are you sure your `client2` string is the same in both `Makefile` and `make client2` call?

Comment: Also, did you name your makefile correctly so make could find it?

Comment: @keltar How would I go about checking this? I rewrote the "client2" string in the makefile just to be sure, one thing to perhaps note is that just using the "make" command without args gives "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

Comment: Got it @MadScientist you're totally right, my bad! I named it "make" instead of "Makefile", when I renamed it and then again added the correct indentation as the tabs seemed to be replaced by spaces after using the "mv" command it now does work. Thank you keltar and MadScientist for your help!

Comment: FWIW, `mv` renames files.  It never modifies the contents of files.  I don't know what happened to your TABs, but `mv` was definitely not the culprit.  If you decide to write makefiles I encourage you to locate a programmer's editor which can be configured to not replace TABs with spaces based on the kind of file that's being edited (most competent programmer's editors will recognize a makefile and switch to this mode automatically).  Glad you fixed your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the ones who commented.

I had the issue named "make" instead of "Makefile", dummy error!
I got it fixed by renaming it to Makefile instead..